# Psycopg2 connection sql database to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, psycopg2

I am working on a project where I am using `psycopg2` connection to fetch the data from the database like this,

```
cursor = connection.execute("select * from table")
cursor.fetchall()
```

Now after getting the data from the table, I am running some extra operations to convert the data from cursor to pandas dataframe. I am looking for some library or some more robust way to convert the data to pandas dataframe from psycopg2 connection.

Any help of guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use pandas sqlio module to run and save query within pandas dataframe.

Let's say you have a connection of psycopg2 `connection` then you can use pandas sqlio like this.

```
import pandas.io.sql as sqlio
data = sqlio.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table", connection)
# Now data is a pandas dataframe having the results of above query.
data.head()
```

For me, sqlio pandas module is working fine. Please have a look at it and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I just tested and it is working the way I wanted. Thank you so much for the quick reply.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you out. Please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Do I need to close the connection?

Comment: @Gobrel - yes you need to. Just tested!

Comment: Note that only the connection objects created through SQLAlchemy are supported, if you use a native psycopg2 connection object there's no guarantee that it will work (it works on my setup but I get a warning).

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for your case:

```py
import pandas.io.sql as sqlio

df = sqlio.read_sql_query(query, connection)
```

Where in your case, `query = "select * from table"`